# How to convert NSString to ASCII value from String Value

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, ascii

if i have string value as `a` it should display as `65` and if it is `b` it should display ASCII equivalent `66` so on anyone please do help!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"A";
int asc = [string characterAtIndex:0];
```