# How to convert a NSString to NSInteger with the sum of ASCII values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ascii

In my Objective-C code I'd like to take a NSString value, iterate through the letters, sum ASCII values of the letters and return that to the user (preferably as the NSString too).

I have already written a loop, but I don't know how to get the ASCII value of an individual character. What am I missing?

```
- (NSString*) getAsciiSum: (NSString*) input {                                                      
    NSInteger sum = 0;                                                                      
    for (NSInteger index=0; index<input.length; index++) {                                  
        sum = sum + (NSInteger)[input characterAtIndex:index];                          
    }                                                                                       
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", sum];                                         
}
```

Note: I've seen similar questions related to obtaining ASCII values, but all of them ended up displaying the value as a string. I still don't know how to get ASCII value as NSInteger.

Comment: And what does say the error?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, works just fine. The only is that the format probably should be `%ld`instead of `%@`.

Comment: @luk2302 is right.. Just change code with : [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)sum];

Comment: To print NSInteger, use %zd. Works on 32 bit and 64 bit without any casts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert NSString to ASCII value from String Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240555/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-ascii-value-from-string-value)

Comment: Consider that @"åß∂ƒ©" is a valid string, and there is no ASCII in sight anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It seems that I've been wrong about which line causes the error. I've corrected the mistake and my function now works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
- (NSString *) getAsciiSum: (NSString *) input
{
    NSString *input = @"hi";
    int sum = 0;
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < input.length; index++)
    {
        char c = [input characterAtIndex:index];

        sum = sum + c;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", sum]);
}
```

This is working for me.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
- (NSInteger)getAsciiSum:(NSString *)stringToSum {
    int asciiSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringToSum.length; i++) {
        NSString *character = [stringToSum substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        int asciiValue = [character characterAtIndex:0];
        asciiSum = asciiSum + asciiValue;
    }
    return asciiSum;
}
```

Thank you to [How to convert a NSString to NSInteger with the sum of ASCII values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944737/how-to-convert-a-nsstring-to-nsinteger-with-the-sum-of-ascii-values/34945269#34945269) for the reference.